# How do I create 4 columns css float left without same height

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

This my current css http://jsfiddle.net/3xcxb/

I want the output to be like this.. [image]

Let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two small changes:

- Use multiple `<ul>`s. I've added a closing `</ul>` after every second `<li>`, and constrained their width in the css. Think of the layout as four columns of two items (or more) each.
- Make the `<ul>`s floated left, instead of the `<li>`s.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/3xcxb/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use vertical columns instead of horizontal rows.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div class="column column1">
        blocks here...
    </div><!-- end .column1 -->
    <div class="column column2">
        blocks here...
    </div><!-- end .column2 -->
    <div class="column column3">
        blocks here...
    </div><!-- end .column3 -->
    <div class="column column4">
        blocks here...
    </div><!-- end .column4 -->
</div><!-- end #container -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3Z3J/1/

Comment: I showed you how to do it, you'll have to learn and do it yourself.